# Change format legend Jfreechart

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart

I'd like to know if it's possible to put the legend that appears on the chart on the x axis in vertical position. First time I am using JFreeChart and I don't know whether it's possible or not.

[image: Chart]
This is my actual code

```
dataset.setValue(VecDias.get(i).GetNpers(),VecDias.get(i).GetHour(),dia_semana);
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart3D("Estadistica     persones/hora", "Hores","Persones",
dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true,true, false);
chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
chart.getTitle().setPaint(Color.black); 
CategoryPlot p = chart.getCategoryPlot(); 
p.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.red); 
LegendTitle legend = chart.getLegend();
legend.setPosition(RectangleEdge.RIGHT);
ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
panel.add(chartPanel);
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on Stack Overflow.So removed it from the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw the Category Labels and change their orientation through the JFreeChart object. First get the `Axis` from the `Plot`, then change the label orientation

```
CategoryPlot p = chart.getCategoryPlot();
CategoryAxis axis = p.getDomainAxis();
axis.setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.UP_90);
```

Note this changes the orientation of the `Category` labels, so you may have to change how the Dataset object is created such that the names of the Categories are correctly reflected.

Comment: Ok, thanks . I just needed to change the position of the values when creating the dataset and then with your tips I got it.